# How to prevent data from being lost when page refreshed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form with text boxes and when I refresh the page all the data is lost can someone help me on how to prevent the data from being lost when the page is refreshed. I've done a lot of research over this but hit a road block after road block, so I really hope your help in this, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding, If you are handling this from client side code the following link will help you.

using Window.sessionStorage you can achieve, the way you want. But you need to handle it appropriately on every key press to store the data into the object and also retrieval.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Answer (score 2):

You can use `localStorage` (feature of HTML5) to `set` and `get` data.

html:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="firstname">
```

Now store the textbox data in localStorage on an event firing as per your requirement.

```
var textBoxdata = $('#firstname').val();
// Store textbox current value
localStorage.setItem("firstnameval", "textBoxdata");
```

and then on `document.ready` check the value if not undefined and populate the textbox with the older value.

```
$(function(){
    // Retrieve textbox previous value
    var value = localStorage.getItem("firstnameval");

    if (typeof(value) !== "undefined") {
        $('#firstname').val(value)
    }
 });
```

check https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged `php` I assume you are using it to render the page? if so, you can have a `$_SESSION` variable that will have an associative array with the fields and values of the form, when rendering you can set the form input value to what is set inside the `$_SESSION` variable.

Also, please add source code if you want better assistance with a problem like this.